# Change textbox value after assigning to variable

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have this code in Javscript.

```
document.getElementById("foo_box").value = 'Hey.';
var foo = document.getElementById("foo_box").value;
document.getElementById("foo_box").value = 'Jude.';
var bar = document.getElementById("foo_box").value;
alert(foo); //alerts 'Jude.'
```

I want it to alert the first value which is 'Hey.'. 
I want to use the variable 'foo' all throughout the code with it containing the first assigned value.
How do I do this?

Comment: You can't `alert()` the first value after setting the value as `Jude` - you've overridden it. Instead, you could always run the alert *before* overriding it (after `var foo`).

Comment: Write the alert after `var foo...`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It alerts "Hey." ~ https://jsfiddle.net/w0su1yuu/

Comment: @ObsidianAge OP never overwrites `foo`. Their assumption is incorrect or their question code does not match reality

Comment: My bad; at quick glance I thought the OP was calling `alert(document.getElementById("foo_box").value)`, which would be `Jude.`.

Comment: Can you show your html ? If your element with id="foo_box" in an input element like `<input id="foo_box" name="input"/>` then the alert will be "hey."  and inputfield content will be "Jude" as per your code.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for this. My code in this example is correct and outputs what I wanted, because this is a simplified version of what I wanted to happen in my real code. It turns out there was another function involved in the current feature I am working on that causes it to produce the wrong output. Thanks to all, especially to @Phil for the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

It prints already "Hey" correctly.

```js
document.getElementById("foo_box").value = 'Hey.';
var foo = document.getElementById("foo_box").value;
document.getElementById("foo_box").value = 'Jude.';
var bar = document.getElementById("foo_box").value;
alert(foo); //alerts 'Jude.'
```

```html
<input id="foo_box" />
```